# Cannot display divs inside div horizontally? (HTML, CSS)

Tags: html, css

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I cannot get 3 divs inside a div to display horizontal in a row. They just seem to stack under each other like a column, i want a row.

I want to use the width value in "%" since I want it to be dynamic and not fixed.

I feel like the error might be that i haven't defined the full scale 100% width to the page, so the 33,33% cannot be relative.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  * background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.header {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

div.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33, 33%;
  padding: 15px;
}

div.row:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}

div.footer {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h2>Rubrik</h2>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus
    quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus
      quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus
      quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus
      quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <h2>Footer</h2>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus
    quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.
  </p>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have an error in your example CSS, `width: 33,33%;` should b 33.33%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

use . instead of ,

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
div.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33,33%; // Using a coma instead of a dot. Must be 33.33%
    padding: 15px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
div.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%; 
    padding: 15px;
}

div.row {
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A common way nowadays is to use `display: flex;` on the container element.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  * background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.header {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

div.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 15px;
}

div.footer {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout1.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h2>Rubrik</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus
      quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <h2>Column</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus
        quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h2>Column</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus
        quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h2>Column</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus
        quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <h2>Footer</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus
      quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- <a href="index.html">Startsida</a> -->
</body>

</html>
```